# eth.getCode() returns empty on geth 1.9

Tags: go-ethereum

I have two nodes connected to the main net. On one I run geth 1.8.27, on the other geth 1.9.1.
When I try to get the code of a smart contract, geth 1.9.1 will not return any code.

Example:

Version: 1.8.27-stable:

```
> eth.getCode("0x7717eFE25b65c8c0fcb97A170B086C17b025A1e1")

"0x60606040526000357c01..."
```

Version: 1.9.1-stable:

```
> eth.getCode("0x7717eFE25b65c8c0fcb97A170B086C17b025A1e1")
"0x"
```

Any ideas why this is happening or what I could try to fix it?

Edit:
maybe worth mentioning that the 1.8.27 node has been running for months while the 1.9.1 has been running for 2 days. Might this be a matter of synchronization? The blocks are fully synced on both.

Version: 1.8.27-stable:

```
 > eth.syncing
false
```

Version: 1.9.1-stable:

```
 > eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 8257358,
  highestBlock: 8257442,
  knownStates: 262464985,
  pulledStates: 262458955,
  startingBlock: 0
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you are not fully synced. The current number of states is more than 300M (mainnet) and the contract code is part of the state sync.